# How to Change a height of jquery mobile header

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jquery mobile. I have one problem. I want to increase the height of a default header.

Now my problem is that i want to increase a size of this header. Can any one tell me how to do it? What css i have to overwrite?

Thanks In Advace
Waiting For Quick Reply 
Aamirkhan I.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can control the height of the header by controlling the height of the div in which you are putting the header tag or data-role="header".
worked for me in case of other jquery-mobile components

Comment: hi! thanks solved i put this line to header div  style="min-height: 45px;"

Comment: please look at this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867677/how-to-fix-header-of-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 12):

The correct way is to modify the ui-title class on the css

Comment: Exactly, as the `.ui-title` defines the height of the header container. Change either the `min-height` or the `line-height` properties. Better yet, change both so the title keeps vertically centered inside your header.

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen and (min-width:720px) {

.ui-btn-text {font-size:36px;}
```

}

I enlarge the font size to get larger header.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. This would be useful if he wants to change the text size of a btn